# Excel IndexOutOfRange with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, excel-interop

Based on the example https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/ExcelDemo I can get Excel interop working in .NET Core 3.1 (yes, I realize Excel isn't exactly cross-platform but bear with me).  The following code runs fine when targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 and but on .NET Core the last line blows up with an IndexOutOfRangeException "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
Excel.Application excel;
Excel.Workbook workbook;
Excel.Worksheet sheet;
Excel.Range range;

// Start Excel and get Application object.
excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = true;

// Get a new workbook.
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

range = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[1, 4]];  //this works fine with .NET Framework but not Core
```

The legacy code I'm attempting to port extensively sets variable ranges like this otherwise I would simply use absolute spreadsheet style indexing like "A1:D1" which seems to work fine in .NET Core.  I've tried setting excel.ReferenceStyle = Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1 as well as permutations of sheet.get_Range(,) instead of sheet.Range[,] but I still get the same out of bounds problem despite it being a valid range.  Any ideas how to get the Range calls working in .NET Core?

Comment: Maybe it's a very silly thing to say, but... what if indexes are zero-based in NET core Excel? Could you try `sheet.Cells[0,0]` instead of `sheet.Cells[1,1]`?

Comment: Same issue with [0,0]. If that were the case it should result in my range being off from the intended location but shouldn't throw an OutOfRange exception.  Typically only the upper bound would be problematic when you run out of rows above 1M+ assuming you never pass anything less than 1.

Comment: In the example code you are pointing, `sheet.get_Range` is used. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I've tried get_Range several different ways:  range = sheet.Cells[1, 1];  //OK
    range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "D1");  //OK
    range = sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1,1], sheet.Cells[1,4]); //IndexOutOfRange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is here, though I don't know why:

you can call like below

```
Excel.Range oCell1 = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
Excel.Range oCell2 = sheet.Cells[1, 4];
range = sheet.Range[oCell1, oCell2];
```

or

range = sheet.Range[(Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1], (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 4]];

Comment: Indeed!  The cast to (Excel.Range) fixes the problem.  For my particular project the Excel export code will eventually be refactored out as it doesn't make sense in a cross-platform scenario. However, I did find a material performance improvement from .NET Core.